# How can I get data from my database in LINQ C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, max

how can i get latest "id" from my database and put this in textbox
note: i have to return latest id from my database.

look at this method :

```
public void refresh()
{
    var query = from qc in db.tbl_viewClients select qc.id  ;
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(query.SingleOrDefault().ToString());
    txt_id.Text = Convert.ToString(a);
}
```

Comment: can you provide more information. what is the table structure.

Comment: Are you sure you want the 'highest number' and not the ID of the row that you just inserted? Because otherwise concurrency can cause trouble. And it's quite inefficient.

Comment: Id or keys are not meant to be shown in the user interface specially database generated values. Can't expect multiple users to see the same top Id and make them think they'll get the top Id + 1 value on their transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle when you have no record because `Max` will throw `InvalidOperationException`.

```
var query = from qc in db.tbl_viewClients select qc.id;
if (query.Any())
{
    var max = query.Max();
    txt_id.Text = max.ToString();
    // do rest of work
}
else
{
   //handle the case when you have no record
}
```

but this approach enumerates the query twice!
Here is a trick!

```
var query = from qc in db.tbl_viewClients select (int?)qc.id;
var max = query.Max();
if (max.HasValue)
{
    txt_id.Text = max.ToString();
    // do rest of work
}
else
{
    //handle the case when you have no record
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `id` is stored as int and  *latest* means *largest id*, you can simply use `Max()`* :

```
int a = query.DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max();
```

Otherwise, information to determine *latest*, such as *creation date*, is missing from the question.

*) added `DefaultIfEmpty(0)` to return `0` in case `query` return no result.

Comment: What if all ids are lesser than zero?

Comment: @dotctor [`DefaultIfEmpty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) only affects the result *in case `query` returns no result*, meaning if there is no id at all in the table. Otherwise, only the actual ids are taken into account.

Comment: I was wrong. Actually something comes to my mind and I explained it in a bad way. The problem with this approach when the result is `0` it is the maximum `id` or there is no record in table.

Comment: Are You sure this works? The SQL generation failed when I used DefaultIfEmpty this way in Linq2SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this please.

```
var query = from t in table orderby t.Id descending
                    select t.Id;

object result =  query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do what I think you are (inserting something into the database, and then querying it to find what you think is the just-inserted-ID), then stop! Doing this will not ensure that the ID you retrieve is the one you need, as your database can, at any time be changed by someone else (concurrency). But still, considering it's just a test, and it's just you who use it and you need to know the ID you just inserted, then the way to do this is:

Assuming you use LINQtoSQL or Entity Framework, when you add an object to the context and call SaveChanges(), right after this the object in question will have its ID (or primary key) field populated. Just check!